# faq jsp page with controller in Spring framework

Tags: jsp

Hi I am new to the Spring framework and I am trying to create a jsp page for frequently asked questions. The jsp page is called *faq.jsp*.  I have a link at the top of the page to click to go to faq page, but I am not sure what code have to use in the controller. I think I have to use request mapping for the page. What I've tried so far has not worked.  Can anyone help me out?

**Link for frequently asked questions:**

```
<div class="faq_menu">
     <a title="Click here for Frequently asked questions"
        href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/faq">
       <img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/images/help.png"       
            alt="faq"  id="faq_menu"/>

       <p>FAQ</p>
     </a>
</div><br/>
```

**In controller page:**

```
 /**
   *
   * @return
   */
   @RequestMapping("/faq")
   public String faq() {    
            return "faq";
   }
```

Comment: What is written is correct, but if you couldn't write more, you should start with a tutorial(just google : spring mvc tutorial). This question is too broad for this site.

Comment: Ok thanks ive since found another way of getting this to work.  I ended up adding java servlet dependencies and it now links my page.